# KeyListener should work and then quit the program but it doesn't(AutoClicker)

Tags: java, system.exit

I've made an AutoClicker and it works fine, but I wanted to add a KeyListener so that the person who's using it can stop the autoclicker it should work with the button q but it doesn't!
Here is the Code:
Main.java:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.*;

public class Main{
    private static Robot roboter = null;
    public static void main(String[]args){
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setSize(1920, 1080);
        jf.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.requestFocus();
        Scanner SekAbstand = new Scanner(System.in);
        int SekundenAbstand;
        int EndlosSchleife = 1;
        System.out.println("Um das Programm zu stoppen druecke Q!!!");
        System.out.println("Wie lange soll der Abstand zwischen den Klicks
        sein(in Millisekunden)?");
        SekundenAbstand = SekAbstand.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Du hast 10 Sekunden um die Maus zur richtigen 
        Position zu bringen!");
        try {
            roboter = new Robot();
        } catch(AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        roboter.delay(10000);
        while(EndlosSchleife == 1) {
            roboter.delay(SekundenAbstand);
            roboter.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            roboter.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        }
    }
}
```

KeyHandler.java:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyHandler implements KeyListener {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Q){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: From my knowledge, KeyListener works only when have focus at your app(for security). To done that without focus, you need to use Java Native Interface and write the part of key listening into C/C++.

Comment: KunLun Problem is I can't program in C/C++

Comment: That mean it will be hard to achieve that, maybe impossible. Java don't give access to SO, security reasons. If someone think I'm wrong, please correct me.